# Generate a db for asp.net program compiled with c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

Its a military based project..while registration form is filled a login form should apppear and validation should be done based on db that is generated automatically.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/da6sI.jpg)

Comment: As identified in the exception (which should be posted as text here, not in an image), the problem seems to be in your connection string. Do NOT post the string here due to privacy, but try to show us the format it is in.

Comment: Code in images can't easily be pasted & reproduced, paste them in question body instead (replace any sensitive data with example ones). Also include SQL connection string where the problem possibly comes from.

Comment: I'm new to asp.net .how to add connection string?

Comment: This link should help. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-strings-and-configuration-files

Comment: Now i'm worried about military security...

Comment: Some information didn't need to be shared - and pseudo code can be written. I do however commend the effort to take a photo of a screen, to then post.